# Access variables from different class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

i need help to read variable from one to another class. I have followed some answers about this but with no success.

PP.h:

```
@interface PP : UIViewController
{
@public int fNum;
}

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int fNum;

- (IBAction)setSomeNum;

@end
```

PP.m:

```
@synthesize fNum;

- (IBAction)setSomeNum
{
fNum = 69;
NSLog(@"Set Num Activated %d",fNum); //OK
}
```

TryView.m:

```
#import "TryView.h"
#import "PP.h"

@interface TryView ()

@end

@implementation TryView
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

PP *obj ;
int x = obj.fNum;
NSLog(@"Happines %d",x); //Prints 0
}
@end
```

What is wrong, why it prints 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're doing is essentially undefined behavior, so be glad it didn't crash.

```
PP *obj ;
int x = obj.fNum;
```

is fundamentally wrong - you are not creating/initializing the object, so `obj` is a dangling pointer, it can point anywere (i. e. to garbage) and crash when accessed. Even if you created the object, you should have called the `setSomeNum` method on it - it doesn't get automagically called (why should it?). All in all, you have to write this:

```
PP *obj = [[PP alloc] init];
[obj setSomeNum];
int x = obj.fNum;
```

etc.

Comment: Actually, he is not lucky. Uninitialized scalars are set to 0 and pointers are set to nil. The object pointing to nil will always return 0 / nil on any getters. A dangling pointer in ObjectiveC is a pointer that once pointed towards something that was released from memory later on.

Comment: @Till no. Only instance variables and global variables are initialized to zero. Function-scope automatic variables are *not* initialized to zero.

Comment: @H2CO3: Except under ARC. All object pointers, including those that are auto, are initialized to `nil` when compiling with ARC.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter thanks. (+1) I don't use ARC neither do I assume others to do so :)

Answer (score 1):

Please, please please read some basic references such as http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/accessormethod.html You aren't using KVO properly, you're using IBActions as setters.

Your actual problem is that you're declaring an object without actually creating it:

```
PP *obj ;

int x = obj.fNum;
NSLog(@"Happines %d",x); //Prints 0
```

But, seriously, this isn't the problem - the real problem is that you don't know the Objective-C language well enough to know what you are doing wrong in this code, and that's the really problem that needs to be fixed.